# React native invoke functions from Swift

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-bridge

Our app needs to do integration with IOT devices and we get the NFC driver framework from device manufacturer. But the lib and APIs from the framework is in Swift. I was able to follow this [tutorial](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) to invoke bridge at objective-c level, but I have no idea how to invoke the function from Swift. Following is an example of swift integration code from the device manufacturer. Thanks in advance.

```
import DeviceLib
class NFCViewController: UIViewController {
    private var nfcDriver: NFCDriver?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.nfcDriver = NFCDriver(delegate: self)
    }
    @IBAction func startNFC(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.nfcDriver != nil {
          do {
                try self.nfcDriver!.sessionBegin()
          } catch {}
    }
}
```

Comment: If the provider of the API exposed functions to ObjC, you'd just call them from your bridge. If they didn't, you need to create an objective-C compatible wrapper for all functions from that lib / API you want to access from react-native. A wrapper will be written in Swift, but it will provide access to its functions from ObjC using `@objc`. For example `@objc func startNFC() { ... }`. So react-native will call  react-native bridge (objC), which will call your wrapper (Swift, exposed to ObjC), which will call functions of that API/lib (pure Swift).

Comment: thanks @thiscommunityistoxic, I did solve the problem by following this tutorial https://teabreak.e-spres-oh.com/swift-in-react-native-the-ultimate-guide-part-1-modules-9bb8d054db03